# Using PHP array for Google E-Commerce

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google E-Commerce with my PHP site. I am using this reference:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#booya

I have got the transaction data working, however I am not sure how to extract the items for the ItemData part. This is an example of my array ($order):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderID] => 823
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [itemQty] => 2
                            [orderID] => 823
                            [price_with_tax] => 30.00
                            [sku] => TOLM386DOGY
                            [title] => The Toledo
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [itemQty] => 1
                            [orderID] => 823
                            [price_with_tax] => 35.00
                            [sku] => BIS73R
                            [title] => The Biscuit

                        )
                )

            [shipping_with_tax] => 5.95
            [grand_total] => 95.00
            [currencyCode] => GBP
        )

)
```

Below are the functions used to create the javascript. I have successfully adjusted the first to get my Order Information, but am struggling with the second to get the item information so have left this as the supplied code from Google for this example:

```
function getTransactionJs(&$order) {
  return <<<HTML
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{$order['0']['orderID']}',
  'revenue': '{$order['0']['grand_total']}',
  'shipping': '{$order['0']['shipping_with_tax']}',
  'currency': '{$order['0']['currencyCode']}'
});
HTML;
}

// Function to return the JavaScript representation of an ItemData object.
    function getItemJs(&$transId, &$item) {
  return <<<HTML
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '{$item['orderID']}',
  'name': '{$item['title']}',
  'sku': '{$item['sku']}',
  'price': '{$item['price_with_tax']}',
  'quantity': '{$item['itemQty']}'
});
HTML;
}
```

This is then output in the following script:

```
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');

<?php
echo getTransactionJs($order);

foreach ($items as &$item) {
 echo getItemJs($order['0']['orderID'], $item);
}
?>

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

My question is what do I need to change in the second function, and potentially the script, to get my item information added to the analytics?

Comment: Actually everything looks good - what are the missing data? You do not see which items were bought in GA? And `$trans['id']` is set? `$trans['id']` should be `$order['0']['orderID']` - correct?

Comment: Hi Jurik - I have updated the code as I have made some adjustments. I have not used `$trans['id']` as I already have the `id` in the item. The problem is the `foreach` for the items is not outputting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $items is not set and with correct error notification you would get a notification for this unset variable. Try this:

```
<?php
  foreach ($order[0]['items'] as $item) {
    echo getItemJs($item);
  }
?>
```

And this is how your function could look like:

```
function getItemJs($item) {
  return <<<HTML
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '{$item['orderID']}',
      'name': '{$item['title']}',
      'sku': '{$item['sku']}',
      'price': '{$item['price_with_tax']}',
      'quantity': '{$item['itemQty']}'
    });
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jurik - that has worked, thank you! Will mark as answer, just one question, I still have the `&$transId` argument in the function, should this be changed or is it ok to leave it?

Comment: Since it is the same number, you can keep it or take it from item array. That is up to you.

Comment: I have tried this but get an error: `function getItemJs(&$item['orderID'], &$item)`